# CamelCase pattern on Kafka Elastic Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was going through Elastic Search best practices and its advice not to used wildcard but to use CamelCase pattern for better performance. Its defined very well in below link

[camelcase_tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html#_camelcase_tokenizer?q=camelcase)

I am using Elastic Search Kafka Connector to consume messages from Kafka topic and pushing back to Elastic Search. I am not able to find how to define CamelCase pattern using Elastic Search connector..Do we have any way to do in Kafka connector context?

Comment: The index needs to be defined with the analyzer ahead of time, AFAIK

Comment: Mean defined index manual not to use automate way?

Comment: That's right. Or update afterwards, maybe. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis

Comment: I think I'd be beneficial to make a PR for index settings, but field analyzers would be more difficult because you'd have to say for which topic patterns contain which fields and then specify analyzer settings within that, and that all would have to be organized in simple property values